# Rounded division by power of 2

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, rounding, bitwise-operators

I'm implementing a quantization algorithm from a textbook.  I'm at a point where things pretty much work, except I get off-by-one errors when rounding.  This is what the textbook has to say about that:

> Rounded division by `2^p` may be carried out by adding an offset and right-shifting by p bit positions

Now, I get the bit about the right shift, but what offset are they talking about?

Here's my sample code:

```
def scale(x, power2=16):
    if x < 0:
        return -((-x) >> power2)
    else:
        return x >> power2
def main():
    inp = [ 12595827, -330706, 196605, -387168, -274244, 377496, -241980, 
            -545272,  -196605, 24198,   196605,  193584, 104858, 424683,
            -40330,     41944 ]
    expect = [ 192, -5, 3, -6, -4, 5, -3, -8, -3, 0, 3, 3, 1, 6, 0, 0 ]
    actual = map(scale, inp)
    for i in range(len(expect)):
        if actual[i] == expect[i]:
            continue
        print 'inp: % 8d expected: % 3d actual: % 3d err: %d' % (inp[i], 
                expect[i], actual[i], expect[i] - actual[i])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm checking for negative input as bit shifting a negative integer appears to be implementation-dependent.

My output:

```
inp:   196605 expected:   3 actual:   2 err: 1
inp:  -387168 expected:  -6 actual:  -5 err: -1
inp:  -196605 expected:  -3 actual:  -2 err: -1
inp:   196605 expected:   3 actual:   2 err: 1
inp:   193584 expected:   3 actual:   2 err: 1
```

What is the offset that is mentioned in the textbook, and how can I use it to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shift will truncate. The shift is a binary operator operating. I'm using square brackets to denote the base here:

```
196605[10] = 101111111111111111[2]
101111111111111111[2] >> 16[10] = 10[2] = 2[10]
```

To perform correct rounding you need to add half of your divisor before doing the shift.

```
101111111111111111[2] + 1000000000000000[2] >> 16[10] = 110111111111111111[2] >> 16[10] = 11[2] = 3[10]
```

Comment: I think it is exactly that truncation that should be used as an offset

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  It solves the exact problem I was having, but introduces new ones.  For example, it won't work for scaling 377496: (377496 + 2**15) >> 16 = 6, whereas the expected answer is 5.

Comment: 377496 / 65536 = 5.760131836. This gets rounded to 6. Therefore the expected answer is 6, not 5. Or have I misunderstood what you mean by rounding?

Comment: @misha: From yuor comments elsewhere I assume you are implementing the quantisation that follows the DCT. This process would not round to the nearest integer. Biasing the rounding process towards smaller integers gives a perceived better video quality. In your code this would mean adding a smaller offset before the shift.

Comment: @qbert220: yes, you're correct.  I also think that rounding towards zero is likely to be the better way to go, as zero coefficients would help during entropy coding.  In that case, how small should the offset be?  I can tell it's likely to be a power of two, but not sure which one.  Thanks for your help so far, by the way, it's been great.

Comment: @misha: I believe it is up to you. The H.264 spec does not specify a precise encoder model. It specifies the syntax and semantics of the stream that needs to be produced and how a decoder should decode a valid stream. It is up to the encoder developer to make such decisions, often based on subjective visual testing.

Comment: I have found a reference in another of Richardson's books that I own (I don't have the one you are using) to a biased quantiser. "An example of a 'biased' forward quantiser design is given in Appendix III of the H.263++ standard: |LEVEL| = (|COEFF| - QUANT/2)/(2 * QUANT)"

Comment: @qbert220: Please explain how ADDing an offset before the shift biases the result towards SMALLER integers. Example: 196605 / 65536.0 produces 2.9999542 but the "expected" value is 3.

Comment: @John: The H.264 quantisation process does not round to the nearest number. It favours rounding to smaller numbers. To round to the nearest number add half the divisor before doing the division/floor. round_nearest = floor((a + (b/2))/b). The H.263++ example uses floor((a + (b/4))/b). This will tend to round to smaller numbers. e.g. remainder of 0.7499 rounds down, 0.75 rounds up.

Answer (score 4):

Shifting by p gives division by 2^p rounded down (truncated).

If you want to divide by 2^p but round to closest integer, do:

```
shift-right by (p-1)
add 1
shift-right 1
```

In your code:

```
def scale(x, power2=16):
    if x < 0:
        return -((((-x) >> (power2-1)) + 1) >> 1)
    else:
        return ((x >> (power2-1)) + 1) >> 1
```

Comment: Rounded division, not truncated division

Comment: @sverre: Yes, corrected it. I took "rounded" as a general term (round down, round up, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I tried using your `scale` function, but still encountered off-by-one errors.  For example, `inp:   377496 expected:   5 actual:   6 err: -1`

Comment: `377496 / 2^16 = 5.76013...` so rounding should give `6`, not `5`. Right?

Comment: @misha so you don't want the closest integer solution, then what do you want?

Comment: @micha: and how did you calculate those expected values you have?

Comment: The expected values come from an example in the textbook.  I want the same solution as what the textbook is giving.  If I knew exactly what they were doing, I wouldn't be asking here :)

Comment: Then the textbook has errors. Your code gives truncating division. Qbert's and mine give rounded division. Check the numbers from the textbook again just to be sure but it's very possible that some of the numbers are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

**As suspected, your algorithm is not actually rounded, but truncating division. What's more is that there are errors in your textbook as well**. So even if you fix your algorithm, you wouldn't get the expected results.

In order to confirm that the results are in fact flawed, you can try running your code with a correct, float-based rounded division function:

```
def scale(x, power2=16):
    divider = float(1<<power2)
    result = round(x/divider)
    return result
```

Yet we get the following errors:

```
inp:   377496 expected:   5 actual:   6 err: -1
inp:  -241980 expected:  -3 actual:  -4 err: 1
inp:   104858 expected:   1 actual:   2 err: -1
inp:   -40330 expected:   0 actual:  -1 err: 1
inp:    41944 expected:   0 actual:   1 err: -1
```

By calculating correct results for rounding division, we can confirm that these expectations, in fact, are faulty:

```
377496 / 65536 = 5,7601 -> should round to 6
104858 / 65536 = 1,600 -> should round to 2
-241980 / 65536 = -3,692 -> should round to -4
104858 / 65536 = 1,600 -> should round to 2
-40330 / 65536 = -0,6154 -> should round to -1
41994 / 65536 = 0,641 -> should round to 1
```

Thus, if rounded division is what you really want, your list of expected values should be:

```
expect = [ 192, -5, 3, -6, -4, 6, -4, -8, -3, 0, 3, 3, 2, 6, -1, 1 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The "expected" answers are just not consistent with one of the possible rounding methods (down, nearest, up) and that's obvious from the positive dividends, before we consider the complications introduced by negative dividends.

```
dividend  exp  float div
   24198    0   0.3692322 DN
   41944    0   0.6400146 D
  104858    1   1.6000061 D
  193584    3   2.9538574  NU
  196605    3   2.9999542  NU
  377496    5   5.7601318 D
  424683    6   6.4801483 DN
12595827  192 192.1970673 DN
```

So down gets 6 out of 8, nearest gets 5, and up gets only 2.

What textbook? It's "Name'n'Shame" time!

**Update** after further experimentation:

If you add 8192 in just before you do the truncating division by 65536, you get the "expected" results. No other power of 2 in (512, ..., 32768) has the same effect.

Describing this as adding an offset to bias rounding downwards is somewhat unfortunate.

Rewrite: The object is to round to the NEAREST integer, but introduce a bias towards zero (smaller absolute integers). Rounding to the nearest would be done by adding in 32768 before the truncating division. Using a smaller "offset" than 32768 gives the desired bias effect. If the offset is a power of 2 e.g 2**k, it can be done by: shift k bits, add 1, shift 16-k bits.

Comment: This is the textbook:  http://www.amazon.com/H-264-Advanced-Video-Compression-Standard/dp/0470516925.  You can get some info about the content at http://www.vcodex.com/h264transform4x4.html but unfortunately the examples are not there.