# Round y=x*x to nearest

Tags: c++, math

Rounding the result of division to the nearest integer is [pretty simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135157/rounded-division-by-power-of-2). But I'm trying to round a result of division so that the subsequent operation will give the best approximation. That's best explained by a simple function:

```
const int halfbits = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits / 2;
unsigned x = foo(); // Likely big.
unsigned x_div = x >> halfbits; // Rounded down
unsigned y = x_div * x_div; // Will fit due to division.
```

I can round `x_div` to nearest by adding `1<<(halfbits-1)`. But since x² is not a linear function, y in general is not rounded correctly. Is there a simple and more accurate way to calculate `(x*x) >> (halfbits*2)` without using bigger types?

I think that adding `3<<(halfbits-3)` to x_div improves the rounding, but can't prove that's the best solution. Also, can this be generalized for xⁿ ?

**Edit**: by popular demand I take the liberty of "translating" the question in pure arithmetic terms (none of these C bit-shifting thing...).
Note: All divisions thereafter are integer divisons, for example 13/3 would be 4.
Problem: We can't compute  x^2 because x is big, so instead we'd like to compute (x^2)/(2^N).
To do so we compute
   x_div = x / sqrt(2^N)
which we then square:
   y = x_div * x_div

However, this result is typically short of the exact value of `(x^2)/(2^N)` and the OP suggests adding 0.5 * sqrt(2^N) or maybe 0.375 * sqrt(2^N) to better approximate the result...

As `Oli Charlesworth`'s answer suggests there's a much better way to get to the actual value, by thinking of `x^2` as  (x_hi + x_lo)^2.

Comment: I'm not lost with the bit ops, but could you perhaps rephrase the operations in a mathmatic centric and less c centric way? Im not trying to be pedantic, i just think it would help clear up the issue at hand and help state your goal.

Comment: Several things to try: `x_div_down*x_div_up`, `x_div_near*x_div_near`. If you are willing to spend the time, you could compute `(x_div*x_rest)>>(halfbit-1)` and correct the result by that.

Comment: So, just to be clear, implied by your `(x*x) >> (halfbits*2)`, you actually want *un-rounded* bit-accurate result of that? Or do you want the mathematical result rounded correctly?

Comment: Wait, isn't `(x*x) >> (halfbits*2)` just `(x*x) >> bits`? Do you mean you're trying to calculate `x^2 / 2^ceil(log2(x))`?

Comment: @Mehrdad: It's actually `x*x/UINT_MAX`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whereas with `x_div` truncation will cause an error magnitude of at most 1, with `x_div*x_div` the error could be up to `1<<(half_digits+2)`.

To see why, consider that we can express this squaring as follows (using [long multplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_multiplication#Long_multiplication)):

```
x * x = (x_lo + x_hi) * (x_lo + x_hi)
      = x_lo^2 + x_hi^2 + 2*x_lo*x_hi
```

where `x_lo` and `x_hi` are the lower and upper halves of `x`, respectively.  With some nice ASCII art, we can consider how these all line up:

```
 MSB     :      :      :     LSB
  +------+------+      :      :
  |    x_hi^2   |      :      :
  +-----++-----++-----+:      :
  :     | 2*x_lo*x_hi |:      :
  :     +------++-----++------+
  :      :      |    x_lo^2   |
  :      :      +------+------+
  :<----------->:      :      :
    Our result
```

As we can see, the lower-order terms affect multiple bits in the final result.

However, each of these terms should fit into the original type without overflow.  So with appropriate shifting and masking, we can get the desired result.

Of course, the compiler/hardware does this all for you if you use a bigger type, so you should just do that if you have the option.

Comment: That's what I was aiming at... however I was suddenly wondering: we do not know whether `x * x` fits into `unsigned`, and it's unclear to me what rounding should be applied to the result...

Comment: @MatthieuM.: It doesn't matter though.  We're only interested in `(x*x) >> (half_bits*2)`.  With appropriate shifting, we can use the above terms to get the correct result.

Comment: Using `n` bits, `x_div` will have `n/2` bits. The max value stored in `n` bits is `2^n - 1`. Because `(2^n -1) - (2^(n/2)-1)*(2^(n/2)-1)` is always greater than zero, we know that `x_div * x_div` will never overflow `n` bits.

Comment: (That is, it's greater than zero for `n` greater than zero, of course.)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Well, it does not matter now that you explained it; but when your answer stopped after the mathematical formula things were less than clear :)

Comment: Just inspected what MSVC2005/ARMv4 managed to create for this, when you let it do this for you. There's hardly any 64 bit arithmetic available, but the compiler still manages to do an impressive job.

Answer (score -4):

Use TYPE int for " y " . I guess that would solve the purpose.

Comment: Note: there's nothing wrong in deleting your wrong answers at SO, and getting 4 downvotes rapidly is generally a good indication that your answer is wrong, even if none of the downvoters bothered to leave an explanation.

Comment: @hyde: Well, one explanation is that this definitely does not "solve the purpose" ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yeah, I definitely did not mean downvotes were wrong. I'm just in the camp which prefers leaving comment when downvoting, even if it is just "your answer is just... wrong".